# Empty response using Bing Spell Check API

Tags: android

I want to implement the Bing Spell Check API in an Android app.
For checking if it function I copy the code example from the Microsoft tutorial and adapt it for my app.
It seems that the request works well and according to the response my text is correct. But the text isn´t correct...
Does someone know this problem or a suitable solution?

In case there is a mistake in my code:

```
protected void requestWebService2(String key) throws IOException {
    final String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
    final String path = "/bing/v7.0/spellcheck";

    final String mkt = "en-US";
    final String mode = "proof";
    final String text = "Hollo, wrld!";

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(host+path);
                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                String encoded_text = URLEncoder.encode (text, "UTF-8");
                String params = "?"+mkt+"&"+mode+"&"+"text="+encoded_text;

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(params);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.i("...", line);
                }
                in.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

And the corresponding entry from console:

```
11-04 16:33:17.310 2662-3904/myapps.webaccess I/...: {"_type": "SpellCheck", "flaggedTokens": []}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corresponding to the solution of Ronak I change the code in the following way (so that it function)

```
try {
       String encoded_text = URLEncoder.encode (text, "UTF-8");
       URL url = new URL(host + path + "?mkt=" + mkt + "&" + "mode=" + mode + "&" + "text=" + encoded_text);
       HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
       connection.setDoOutput(true);

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
       String line;
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("...", line);
       }
       in.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a minor bug in the code sample provided. You need to modify **params** string to:

```
String params = "?mkt=" + mkt + "&" + "mode=" + mode + "&" + "text=" + encoded_text;
```

`mkt` and `mode` are missing in the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems so that I was blind :D
Unfortunately it was not the whole solution, because after fixing the code, the response remains the same...

Comment: Does it work now, with the code you posted above? I can spend more time to get that to work :).